# Migrating html & css website into wordpress issue

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, migrate

Hello fellow developers,

I have an issue that I am running up against regarding WordPress and the current website I am working on.

I have been give a task to revamp a website, and to insert that website into WordPress. I have been working on a "custom theme" which I succeeded in luckily. The problem with that theme is, the theme shows the homepage of the website I have revamped, and when I wish to add another page to said WordPress installation. All it shows is a blank editor page.. (The same with the "view" and "edit") on the homepage of that website.

TL;DR

I want to use my custom theme to add another page to the wordpress website, problem is it shows a blank page. And the preview of a new page just shows the theme page (so the add page refuses to do anything).

Is there a good and efficient way to migrate my current HTML & CSS website to wordpress? If so how?

Thanks for the read, it's really hard to explain the situation

Answer (score 0):

So the problem comes when you try to add a new page, within WordPress? Did you accidentally edit that function? Try reinstalling WordPress. Since your theme is ready, you will just need to copy it to the new installation.

Comment: I haven´t edited anything within my wordpress installation, so i can rule that out luckily. The thing is that I have an index.php file which contains the content of the page, and the header and footer.php are containing those two. Things is that no matter what i try or do, i cannot edit any page or view those pages. Since all i can see is the `theme` home page (aka the homepage of the site i try to migrate).

Comment: Also, whenever i try to edit the index file (in wordpress) it just shows the wordpress editor without ANY theme installed whatsoever. However, when i "view" said page. It shows the page as it should be